# Time difference in R

Tags: r

I have some data which looks like this:

```
id    time
1     2013-02-04 02:20:59
1     2013-02-04 02:21:05
1     2013-02-04 02:21:24
2     2013-02-04 02:21:26
2     2013-02-04 02:22:19
2     2013-02-04 02:22:35
```

I want to take the difference in time for each id between two time values such as for:

```
id 1 02:21:05-02:20:59=00:00:06.
```

How can I do this in R?

Comment: You want the difference in time between each row?

Comment: Are you just after `diff(df$time)`?

Comment: yes i want the difference in time for each row but only when the id is the same.

Comment: No diff did'nt work as i need to subtract between two corresponding rows.

Comment: Will you expect just two rows of output for `id = 1` and another two rows of output for `id = 2`?

Comment: Can you use `dput(head(YOUR_DATA))` instead?  This is not a good format to read in as you have no row names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a  grouping solution using the base package using `by` and `transform`

```
   transform(dat, res = unlist(by(time,as.factor(id),
                            FUN=function(x)c(0,diff(x)))))
```

This will work for a factor id , which is the natural type for a grouping column.

Comment: @geektrader I assumed that data is ordered by id and by time for each id. Here the point is to use the right data type. I think also that your solution don't work with no ordered id.

Comment: right data type here will in fact be a integer if this needs to be done "vector" way..  PS: my solution works for unordered id, as my interpretation of question is that diff in time is needed when two consecutive id's are same.

Answer (score 3):

You should do `diff` on time as well as `id` and then using `ifelse` populate the third column

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
        time = structure(c(1359915659, 1359915665, 1359915684, 
        1359915686, 1359915739, 1359915755), class = c("POSIXct", 
        "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), .Names = c("id", "time"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), 
        class = "data.frame")
df
##   id                time
## 1  1 2013-02-04 02:20:59
## 2  1 2013-02-04 02:21:05
## 3  1 2013-02-04 02:21:24
## 4  2 2013-02-04 02:21:26
## 5  2 2013-02-04 02:22:19
## 6  2 2013-02-04 02:22:35

## here you are checking if that result is diff in time only when diff in id is 0
df$result <- c(0, ifelse(diff(df$id) == 0, diff(df$time), 0))

df
##   id                time result
## 1  1 2013-02-04 02:20:59      0
## 2  1 2013-02-04 02:21:05      6
## 3  1 2013-02-04 02:21:24     19
## 4  2 2013-02-04 02:21:26      0
## 5  2 2013-02-04 02:22:19     53
## 6  2 2013-02-04 02:22:35     16
```

Comment: +1! although here that this will not work when id is factor(or string).

Comment: @agstudy: i did face that exact problem that u mentioned so i just created a unique numeric key for each string id.

Comment: @SanjanaHaralalka this is inefficient. You will store all the numeric in memory, but using a factor you will store only the distinct group. see my solution with a factor.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work, but I'm not entirely clear on your requirement...

```
df <- data.frame(id = rep(c(1,2), each=3), time=seq(from = as.POSIXct("2013-02-04 02:20:59"), to=as.POSIXct("2013-02-04 02:22:35"),length.out=6))

library(plyr)
df.diff <- ddply(df, .(id), summarise,
                 difference = diff(as.numeric(time)))
df.diff
# id diff
# 1  1 19.2
# 2  1 19.2
# 3  2 19.2
# 4  2 19.2
```