# Flexible calculations in data frames

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a little problem with **R** and my skills are somehow limited.
I want to conduct two calculations in a data frame which are based on the previous row.
The first one is a count variable, additionally I want to calculate the difference between the current and the previous line.

I think the easiest way to clarify my problem is a small example:

Imagine the following table below, which consists of only two columns. `user` is a customer number and `time` is the time of a transaction of the particular user.

Now I want to create two new columns as specified in the example table:

1. The counter variable `count`, which simply counts the transactions of the user, indicating the actual number of the actual user's transaction.
2. The variable `diff (time [s])`, which is the time difference [in seconds] between the current transaction and the previous one. Thus something like: time [i] - time [i-1], but the calculation for each new user must start again from zero; obviously no time difference can be calculated for the first transaction of each user.

I've tried to solve this problem with a loop, however the table is very large and the calculation on the complete data set just didn't want to end.

```
user    time    count   diff(time[s])
A   10:00:00    1   
A   10:30:00    2   1.800
A   12:00:00    3   5.400
A   13:00:00    4   3.600
B   14:00:00    1   
C   15:00:00    1   
C   16:00:00    2   3.600
C   17:00:00    3   3.600
```

Comment: Answers for your first variable can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17923466/count-of-records-within-levels-of-a-factor), among other places.

Comment: And answers for the second can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15353731/time-difference-in-r), among other places.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it using the `plyr` package, which makes life a lot easier when it comes to data wrangling. There are ways to do this and other transformations in base R, but it's a mess of different functions with inconsistent interfaces.

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df, .(user), transform, count=seq_len(time), diff=c(0, diff(time)))
```